# Why when I swap those 2 lines the program doesn't fill the array

Tags: c

I have a program who should return the following:

```
    0
    0    1
    0    1    1
    0    1    2    1
    0    1    3    3    1
    0    1    4    6    4    1
```

But it returns just the first line and exit, like if the array is empty.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  int P[5][5];
  int N = 5;
  int I, J;

  for (I = 0; I <= N; I++) {
    P[I][I] = 1;
    P[I][0] = 0;
    for (J = 1; J < I; J++) {
        P[I][J] = P[I - 1][J] + P[I - 1][J - 1];
    }
  }

  for (I = 0; I <= N; I++) {
    for (J = 0; J <= I; J++)
    {
        printf("%5d", P[I][J]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

But if I swap the two lines (4, 5) and make P[5][5] -> P[N][N] the code works fine and return the desired value.

```
int N = 5;
int P[N][N];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`P[5][5]` is too small; that creates an array with indices from 0 to 4 in each dimension, but you use 0 to 5. Change it to `P[6][6]`.

Swapping the lines and changing the definition to use `N` for the dimension changes where the compiler allocates memory for the array. In either case, the program overruns the allocated memory, but the change in location affects how destructive the overrun is to proper execution of the program.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that initializing P with P[5] gives you the possibility to stock something in P[5]. By the way I am newbie in C.

Comment: Pardon my silly question, It's been more than 24 hours I am still overwhelmed with this problem.
I understand that the array is small but why when I use N to set the array size it works ? Is it a coincidence that the additional needed bytes are free or what ?
Please tell me if there's something that I should understand first.

Comment: @HatimLagzar: Yes, it is likely a coincidence, in effect. When the array is declared with constant sizes, the compiler may allocate a specific place for it in the function’s stack frame. When it is declared with a variable size, the compiler may put it in a different place, after the portion of the stack frame used for known-size things. The memory beyond the array may not be free in either case, but what it is used for differs depending on where it is. In one case, writing outside the array changed something that broke the program…

Comment: … In the other case, it changed something else, and it did not happen to immediately break the program in a visible way. It is like you jammed a screwdriver through a machine. If you get lucky, you might not hit a critical part, and the machine might keep working. If you jam it through a different place, the machine might break.

Comment: Thank you so much Eric, I don't know how I forgot to thank you sorry...